# Yii2- Not able to insert/delete rows using console controller

Tags: activerecord, yii2, console-application

I am trying to implement email queue in my project which uses CRON.
I am adding a row in one table and deleting a row from another table using CreateCommand of yii2. Database is mysql.

The entire code is executed and it does not display any error. But the rows are not added or deleted from the database.

I have also tried doing the same thing using ActiveRecords but it does not work. Hence I have used CreateCommand.

Below is the code which I am using -

```
$connection  = \Yii::$app->db;
$result = $connection->createCommand()->insert('email_queue_completed',   $arrInsert)->execute();
if(!empty($result))
{   
   $connection->createCommand()
       ->delete('email_queue', ['id' => $mail->id])
       ->execute();
}
```

$arrInsert is an array containing key value pairs of values to be inserted.

Comment: please debug your $arrInsert

Comment: I have done that. Only delete is also not working.

Comment: have you debug, $mail->id has value or not, code is looking fine. Please debug with static value

Comment: check `$mail->id` by `var_export($mail->id);`

Comment: $mail->id shows me correct ID.